# Windows Workflow Foundation in ASP.NET 3.5 Web Application - Best Approach

Tags: workflow, asp.net-3.5, workflow-foundation, architecture

What is the best way to use Windows Workflow Foundation in ASP.NET 3.5 Web Application.

In my case there are several workflows(sequential) which includes numerous steps,  user has the privilege to save and exit  at any of these steps; the state must be persisted,  possibly in SQL Server. 
Exposing workflows as web service is good idea? I have very little idea about workflows and only tried out wf console applications.

Please guide me in right direction, also I would like to know is there any specific and established architecture to use wf in ASP.NET Web Apps. We have layered architecture for our web apps (BLL, DAL, Services etc) and I would like to know where we can incorporate workflows in current architecture.

Many thanks in advance.

> **Update**: thank you Rubens Farias for helping me out in first place.
>   We are still unsure which approach will be the best.
>   Please provide any example frameworks or sample webapplication which use workflow
>   So far...
>   1. Is it good idea to use [Page Flow Application Block](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Page%20Flow%20Application%20Block)
>   2. There are lots of changes in [WF4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx), should I wait for that?
>   3. Or use WF as Rubes Farias suggested
>
> Please guide me friends, am desperate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely must read this document: [Foundations: Workflow Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164251.aspx)

You can to add an out-of-box persistence service, so your workflows get persisted into a SQL Server database, and to expose them as WCF services (RESTfull approaches is also available).